# Intuition around monoids in category theory

Tags: category-theory

Software developer trying to build some elementary intuition around monoids in category theory. I've read some writings on this topic, including other similar questions here on math.stackexchange, e.g.:

- [Monoid as a single object category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332690/monoid-as-a-single-object-category)
- [Category with only one object.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907064/category-with-only-one-object)
- [Trying to understand significance of monoid as a one object category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957526/trying-to-understand-significance-of-monoid-as-a-one-object-category)

but nobody seems to be asking or explaining it from this angle (or I'm not understanding them).

I understand the monoid concept. Take the usual example (Int, +, 0). I have a good intuition there. I know that 1 + 2 = 3, (1 + 2) + 3 = 1 + (2 + 3) and 0 + 1 = 1 = 1 + 0. I understand that + goes from one element of the Int set to another element of the Int set.

Translated to a monoid category, I now have one object A and a set of morphisms 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ... from A to A. Identity is there, composition holds. That part is all good. Now, how do I "use" this? The above knowledge / intuition from the monoid does not seem to apply. All I have now is a bounch of arrows A -> A and whichever of these arrows I "travel" aboard, I end up at the same place, so what's the point?

What am I missing? Also, are there online resources that approach this from this angle that I can go through?

Comment: I can give you, if you'd like it, one or two related examples of how a notion is defined usefully for a specific category, then it is naturally generalized for arbitrary categories, and then you get a meaningful specialization to 1-object categories i.e. to monoids.This may give you an idea how mathematical notions from general categories can migrate to monoids. I am not sure that you're looking for this kind of an answer--let me know, if you say "yes". (Otherwise, peace, I may even remove this comment, no harm meant).

Comment: @WlodAA Absolutely! I mean, I guess that's the hard thing about building intuition, it's not obvious where to start and how to proceed. Being a beginner, it's hard to read through all the foreign notation efficiently. I say: unless you feel it's not on-topic (so you don't get downvoted otherwise), I think anything you add in the worst case cannot be bad, so let's be optimistic: it might help greatly! :) Even if it doesn't click for me, it might help others.

Comment: If you like, you may email to annarborwlod, then add @, and my email provider is gmail.com. *** I part with this forum math.stackexchange.com. My name is Włodzimierz Holsztyński.

Comment: But a monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors.

Comment: A brief response to "I end up at the same place" is that you're still making the mistake of thinking categories are about the *objects*. The *morphisms* of a category are just as important to what a category "is" -- in fact arguably they are *more* important than the objects.

Comment: @Hurkyl I've read that many times. The question is: how do I use that fact to get a better understanding of category theory concepts?

Answer (score 5):

I have four answers, which I've given in ascending order of how satisfactory I think they are for your purposes. If you're short on time, skip to the end.

1. The most unsatisfactory answer I can give is that a category is the [horizontal categorification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal%20categorification) of a monoid.
2. Another unsatisfactory answer is that there is a correspondence between one-object categories and monoids. Indeed:

   - For any small category $\mathcal{C}$ with a single object $A$, the set $\mathcal{C}(A,A)$ of morphisms $A \to A$ is a monoid, with unit element $\mathrm{id}_A$ and binary operation given by composition.
   - For any monoid $(M, \cdot, e)$, there is a one-object category $\mathcal{C}$ with a single object $A$ whose morphisms are the elements of $M$, with $\mathrm{id}_A=e$, and such that composition is given by $\cdot$.
3. A perhaps more satisfactory answer is this. Monoids can act on sets, and monoids are entirely determined by how they act on sets. Given a monoid $M$ and a set $X$, a (left) action of $M$ on $X$ is a function $M \times X \to X$, written $(m,x) \mapsto mx$, satisfying the condition that $ex=x$ and $(mn)x=m(nx)$ for all $m,n \in M$ and $x \in X$. By considering a monoid as a one-object category in the above sense, specifying a set with a monoid action is exactly the same as specifying a functor $M \to \mathbf{Set}$. Thus the one-object category corresponding with a monoid $M$ can be thought of, in some sense, as the 'generic set with $M$-action': the single object behaves as a placeholder for a set to be acted on by $M$, and the morphisms describe how $M$ acts on the set.
4. Hopefully the most satisfactory answer is this: your intuition of categories is too grounded in sets *(or graphs?—see Derek Elkins's comment below)*. You're thinking of a morphism of a category as being a transformation from one thing to another, like a function. Whilst this intuition is helpful for concrete categories, such as the categories of sets, groups, rings, monoids, topological spaces, etc., there are *many* examples of categories where it is *not* helpful to think of the morphisms as functions (or transformations of any sort). Your question is itself an illustration of this!

Comment: My impression is that the OP's intuition is too grounded in *graphs*. No one says "this function has the same domain and codomain, so what's the point?" We don't consider functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ uninteresting because they just take us from and to the set of natural numbers and thus you "end up at the same place".

Comment: @DerekElkins: That's a very good point. It's hard to answer questions that end in "so what's the point?" - I get the feeling that any response we give will be met with some degree of hostility!

Comment: @DerekElkins "too grounded in graphs" So how do I lift myself up from the ground? :) How do I look at this in a different way? "We don't consider functions N→N uninteresting" I feel I'm missing something here too, but: the  difference for me is that I always hear that in CT you don't look "inside" the objects, just consider their relationships, while when working with N→N functions you definitely do in many cases, no?

Comment: @CliveNewstead I'll try to digest what you said, the first read did not click much unfortunately. "some degree of hostility" haha true! In some cases though, the anticipation is unwarranted :) "You're thinking of a morphism of a category as being a transformation from one thing to another" What's the proper (or alternative) way to think about morphisms?

Answer (score 2):

Being a programmer myself, I understand where you're coming from. In order to "use" a monoid in programming, it has to be part of a larger category of types and functions. For that, we need a more general definition of a monoid--as an object in a monoidal category.

You probably have a pretty good intuition about a monoidal category: it's a category in which you can define a product of two objects. In programming we call it a product type, or a tuple. The tupling is associative, up to isomorphism. There is also a unit object, with the property that, when tupled with any other object, it gives you something that's isomorphic to that object. In programming that's a unit type (it corresponds to a singleton set).

I don't know what your programming language of choice is, so I'll stick to Haskell. Product of two types `a` and `b` is a pair type `(a, b)`. The unit type is denoted by an empty tuple `()`. So the category of types and functions that we use in programming is monoidal (it's even more than that--it's bicartesian closed, but that's another story).

We can now define a monoid in a monoidal category. It's an object `m` together with two morphisms, multiplication:

```
mu :: (m, m) -> m
```

and unit:

```
eta :: () -> m
```

These two morphisms have to satisfy some laws that guarantee associativity and left and right unit laws.

The intuition is that `mu` assigns to every pair of elements the result of "multiplication," and `eta` picks the special element that's the unit with respect to that "multiplication."

This is a definition of a monoid that is much more useful in programming. You can have many different monoids sitting in the same monoidal category. You can even have multiple monoids defined on top of the same object (e.g., the integer type with multiplication or addition).

If you're curious, a general monoidal category is defined with respect to a more general tensor product that must satisfy some properties that make it associative and unital.